# Import image in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, webpack

```
import mainSampleImg from 'images/my_img.jpg';

class ImageCard extends Component {
  imgDiv = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.bgImgPath) {
      const image = new Image();

      var test={mainSampleImg}; # the value of test is {"mainSampleImg": "my_img.jpg?1ecdc36e"}
   
      image.src = {mainSampleImg};# the value of image.src is http://localhost:8080/proxy/[object%20Object]
    
    }
  }

  ...
```

Since `img.src` has value `http://localhost:8080/proxy/[object%20Object]`, it becomes images not found, what is the right way to specify the images from `images/my_img.jpg`? (just for info, I am using webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign an object to `image.src` instead of a string:

```
// not { mainSampleImg }
image.src = mainSampleImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put images in your public folder then you can just import like so:

`<img src={'/path/under/public/route/filename.jpg} />`

so if you have `public` folder with `images` directory and file is `football.jpg` you would do:

`<img src={'/images/football.jpg'} />`

no need to import images at the top of the file